# NSURLProtocol. requestIsCacheEquivalent never called

Tags: ios, caching, nsurlsession, nsurlcache, nsurlprotocol

I'm not sure what the deal is here, but the function:

```
class func requestIsCacheEquivalent(a: NSURLRequest, toRequest b: NSURLRequest) -> Bool
```

is never called within my NSURLProtocol subclass. I've even seen cases of the cache being used (verified by using a network proxy and seeing no calls being made) but this method just never gets invoked. I'm at a loss for why this is.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I have requests that I'd like to cache data for, but these requests have a signature parameter that's different for each one (kind of like a nonce). This makes it so the cache keys are not the same despite the data being equivalent.

To go into explicit detail:

1. I fire a request with a custom signature (like this: 
   `www.example.com?param1=1&param2=2&signature=1abcdefabc312093`)
2. The request comes back with an Etag
3. The Etag is supposed to be managed by the NSURLCache but since it thinks that a different request (`www.example.com?param1=1&param2=2&signature=1abdabcda3359809823`) is being made it doesn't bother.

I thought that using NSURLProtocol would solve all my problems since Apple's docs say:

```
class func requestIsCacheEquivalent(_ aRequest: NSURLRequest,
                      toRequest bRequest: NSURLRequest) -> Bool
```

> YES if aRequest and bRequest are equivalent for cache purposes, NO
>   otherwise. Requests are considered equivalent for cache purposes if
>   and only if they would be handled by the same protocol and that
>   protocol declares them equivalent after performing
>   implementation-specific checks.

Sadly, the function is never called. I don't know what the problem could be...

```
class WWURLProtocol : NSURLProtocol, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {
var dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask?
var session: NSURLSession!
var trueRequest: NSURLRequest!

private lazy var netOpsQueue: NSOperationQueue! = NSOperationQueue()
private lazy var delegateOpsQueue: NSOperationQueue! = NSOperationQueue()

override class func canInitWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> Bool {
    println("can init with request called")
    return true
}

override class func canonicalRequestForRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> NSURLRequest {
    println("canonical request for request called")
    return request
}

override class func requestIsCacheEquivalent(a: NSURLRequest, toRequest b: NSURLRequest) -> Bool     {
    // never ever called?!?
    let cacheKeyA = a.allHTTPHeaderFields?["CacheKey"] as? String
    let cacheKeyB = b.allHTTPHeaderFields?["CacheKey"] as? String

    println("request is cache equivalent? \(cacheKeyA) == \(cacheKeyB)")

    return cacheKeyA == cacheKeyB
}

override func startLoading() {
    println("start loading")

    let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let config = sharedSession.configuration
    config.URLCache = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache()
    self.session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: self.delegateOpsQueue)

    dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, nil)
    dataTask?.resume()
}

override func stopLoading() {
    println("stop loading")
    dataTask?.cancel()
}


//SessionDelegate

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: NSError?) {
    println("did become invalid with error")
    client?.URLProtocol(self, didFailWithError: error!)
}


func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
    println("did complete with error")
    if error == nil {
        client?.URLProtocolDidFinishLoading(self)
    } else {
        client?.URLProtocol(self, didFailWithError: error!)
    }
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
    println("did receive response")
    client?.URLProtocol(self, didReceiveResponse: response, cacheStoragePolicy: .Allowed)
    completionHandler(.Allow)
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
    println("did receive data called")
    client?.URLProtocol(self, didLoadData: data)
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, willCacheResponse proposedResponse: NSCachedURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSCachedURLResponse!) -> Void) {
    println("will cache response called")
    client?.URLProtocol(self, cachedResponseIsValid: proposedResponse)

    completionHandler(proposedResponse)
}
```

I registered the protocol in my app delegate as follows:

```
NSURLProtocol.registerClass(WWURLProtocol.self)
```

I trigger the protocol as follows:

```
@IBAction func requestData(endpointString: String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: endpointString)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    var cacheKey = endpointString
    request.setValue("\(endpointString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "CacheKey")
    request.cachePolicy = .UseProtocolCachePolicy

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: netOpsQueue) { (response, data, error) -> Void in
        if data != nil {
            println("succeeded with data:\(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)))")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in practice, the loading system just uses the canonicalized URL for cache purposes, and does a straight string comparison.  I'm not certain, though.  Try appending your nonce when you canonicalize it, in some form that is easily removable/detectable (in case it is already there).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems all right.You just follow documents of Apple about `URLProtocol`.You could try to use `URLSession` for `NSURLConnection` is deprecated in newer iOS version.Good luck.